# How to automate adduser (on linux) when add new user site in multisite

Tags: multisite, linux, multisite-user-management

Like certain control panel like Cpanel or VestaCP, once new user created, it automatically adduser into linux. The purpose to do this is to monitor resource usage by each wordpress multi user.

How to do the same just using Wordpress Multisite to automate adduser (on linux) when add new user site?

Comment: So... you want to run the webserver, PHP, and MySQL processes serving a request to multisite as a different Linux user depending on which site is requested?

Comment: @bosco yes exactly. So any multisite admin created will also automatically create a linux user too and able to see who is the resource hog culprits

Answer (score 0):

It will be a problematic thing to do as it will require you to let the webserver run scripts as a system root. It is somewhat hard and requires a lot of thinking security wise about the implications of letting a web server do it.

But you are spared of all that thinking ;) as your scheme is not practical as wordpress MU always runs as the webserver user and you will not be able to associate  resource usage with different system users. To actually achieve what you want you will need to create separate wordpress install for each new user.

Comment: Ya. You're right. I haven't try yet, but theoretically I'm thinking about seperated 2 different php memory limit server. But using same database (remote and ignoring mysql memory limit). Server A 128mb and server B 256mb. But when creating user for 128mb I will use server A. And vice versa so fies will remains only on where they shoud be and limit php memory usage. The problem I can think right now is domain mapping for our superadmin. What your suggestions?